# Swift syntax, and understanding certain parts of the language

Tags: ios, swift, syntax

I have read the basic's on the Swift programming language such as variables, classes, functions etc. What I don't understand is when I start trying to build an application, is the structure of how you set up a function. I am guessing **function**, or what I list below. I will elaborate the best I can.

I'd like to understand how people know, or where to learn what to put when your trying to accomplish something.

For example I Googled making a HTTP call and this code came up:

```
let request = URLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY")! as URL)
do {
    // Perform the request
    var response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<URLResponse?>? = nil
    let data = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returning: response)
```

I get totally lost on the part with:

```
URLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY")! as URL)
```

Where do you read to learn when to use things such as URLRequest, or how or when to put url: in front of it. Even though this is just one example, I notice in building a swift application you guys use things such as NSUrl, NSObject, URLRequest. And in the documentation I have not learned about these things. And I don't understand how you guys know when to put question marks "?", or how you format it your functions like the example above.

If I am not asking this correctly, I can always explain more.

If you know what I can search for online so I can know what I am trying to learn, that would be helpful. Or a book that teaches you about UIWindows, and basic functions using stuff like NSObject and UIWindows that would be helpful.

**What is difficult is understanding the API documentation. If you can't understand the api documentation, and syntax. How can you ever learn. I guess its easier, to learn by example sometimes.**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Raymond! This is a really broad question; not really good for SO's format. Everybody learns in different ways, so there's no easy way to tell you how to learn this information. There are a ton of books out there, as well as online courses that can start you out. At first, you'll be lost, as you are now; however, the more you code, the more you start to understand. When you have a specific question, look that up. You'll find all kinds of other stuff at the same time. Pretty soon, you'll be really good at searching and understanding!

Comment: First Since Swift 3 You should use URL instead of NSURL. Second sendsynchronousrequest is deprecated. You should use URLSession instead. Third asking for a book is off topic at SO.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate the responses everyone. I was not confused specifically on NSURL. But how you structure stuff like that.

Comment: Btw if you would like to learn about how to download data from a url you can check this https://code.bradymower.com/swift-3-apis-network-requests-json-getting-the-data-4aaae8a5efc0

Comment: You dont need NSURL anymore. Just drop the NS and use URL instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, because your question hasn't been closed as too broad, and because it has upvotes, I'll try to give you at least a start on what I think you were actually asking...

#### Where to find out what this stuff means:

First, for Swift, you want to read [The Swift Programming Language: A Swift Tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html). This will give you a really good beginner's overview of the language and how to use it. It includes a [downloadable Swift Playground](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.playground.zip) that includes the entire tour and allows you to try things out and practice what you're learning.

Next, when you see something, like `URLRequest`, you can look it up in the [Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlrequest). To get to this documentation, you can search on the name and the text "developer documentation". Alternatively, you can go to the [Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation) and search from there. Finally, you can look it up in Xcode's documentation window: from the Xcode menu, Window -> Developer Documentation.

Often, the developer site will also provide [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=urlrequest&type=Sample%20Code) as well. This is really cool, 'cause you can download it, play with it, and per the license information, use it in your own code. This code also usually has remarks and descriptions throughout that help you understand what it's doing. *The sample code is a really good way of learning when and how to use the different functions you come across!*

Now, having said that, the documentation itself (separate from the sample code) can be quite confusing for a beginner. However, as you gain experience, you'll understand more of what it's trying to tell you.

#### What the documentation tells you:

Let's walk through the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlrequest) for `URLRequest`:

[image: URLRequest Reference Documentation]

At the top, you see that this is a `Structure`, not a `Class`. In the Swift Tour, you'll learn the difference.

Under the name `URLRequest`, you see a description. The description here is usually about as clear as mud for a newbie. However, some descriptions are followed by detailed and really good information about the item. For an example of this, take a look at the [UIViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller).

At the right side of the page, you find when the item became available (`URLRequest` has been available since iOS 7, for example), which framework you need to import to use it (`Foundation`, here), and links to other information.

"Topics" lists the properties and functions you can use to do various things. For example, you might want to "create a request" or "work with a cache policy" using an `URLRequest` object.

[image: URLRequest "Topics" Section]

"Relationships" gives you information about inheritance and protocols to which the item conforms. These items show other properties and methods that can be used in a given object. Again, these can be confusing for beginners, but you'll eventually get it. For example, `URLRequest` conforms to `Equatable`. That means you can compare `urlRequest1 == urlRequest2` or `!=` as well.

[image: URLRequest "Relationships" Section]

Finally, the "See also" section shows you other things that are related to this one. You can use this section to learn more about items you might want to use along with the one you're currently viewing.

[image: URLRequest "See also" Section]

#### How your example breaks down:

The particular example you picked is creating or "instantiating" a new `URLRequest` object:

```
URLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY")! as URL)
```

Therefore, it would use the "topic" regarding "creating a request". That shows us:

```
init(url: URL, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy, timeoutInterval: TimeInterval)
    Creates and initializes a URL request with the given URL and cache policy.
```

Now, it turns out that the "creating a request" topic is actually missing a function here. Go to a Swift playground, and enter `URLRequest(`, stopping at the left paren. You'll see that two items appear: one that shows the above (without the `init` part), and one that just shows `(url: URL)`. I'll get back to that in a sec...

Newbies might not realize they don't need to use the `init` part shown in the documentation. You can use `URLRequest.init(...)` if you want, but you can simplify that to just `URLRequest(...)`, with the dots representing what goes inside, of course. So, back to the missing initializer, it should appear in the documentation as:

```
init(url: URL)
```

That's the one your example is actually using, so I'll cover it going forward.

The parts that go inside the parentheses are "parameters" or "arguments". (There's a subtle difference, but many developers use these two terms interchangeably.) You'll learn in the Swift Tour that if a label is required, it'll be there; otherwise, it'll have an underscore (`_`). So, here, you must have a label for `url:`. If you type this in Xcode 9, you'll get:

```
URLRequest(url: URL)
```

Xcode provides the labels you need to have, and it's giving you hints as to how to fill in the blanks: at the `url:` label, you need to provide a `URL`-type object.

The labels represent the variable name you'd use to access that piece of information, if you were writing a function yourself. Since this is a `Foundation`-provided function, it's the variable name the URLRequest initialization function would use inside itself, hidden (or "encapsulated") away from your eyes, but necessary to create a `URLRequest`.

Now, your example can be broken into two parts. Since they needed a `URL` object, they created it *inside* the `url:` argument. This example could be broken down to something like the following:

```
let nsURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY")! as URL
let request = URLRequest(url: nsURL)
```

The NSURL command, though, is actually from Objective-C. (As a rule of thumb, anything starting with `NS` is coming from Objective-C. As these get converted into pure Swift, the `NS` goes away.) Swift has it's own version of `NSURL` now, so the example code is "casting" or changing the `NSURL` into an `URL` at the end. This could be rewritten entirely in Swift as:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY")
let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
```

#### What the question and exclamation marks mean:

The question mark indicates an "optional" value, while the exclamation point is "force-unwrapping an optional" value. This is discussed in the tour, but is probably one of the most confusing aspects of Swift 'til you finally get it. Consider this example:

```
// This is supposed to be a String value - but it's empty right now ("nil").
// Therefore, I put a '?' on the type name to tell Swift that it's a String,
// but it could be nil (meaning it's value is "optional" - it may be there or not)
let nilString: String? = nil

// I'll go ahead and give the string a value here:
nilString = "I'm not nil anymore."

// Now, I'll use this String value - but I told Swift it might be empty!
// I can tell Swift that I'm CERTAIN a value is present by "force unwrapping" it:
// that is, indicating I'm sure it's not nil by adding a '!'
let newString = nilString! + "testing"
```

If I had tried to use the value while it was still `nil`, Swift would yell at me: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

Okay. I believe I've covered most of what you were actually asking, so ending my "book" here before the SO masters kick me out! You can make this the answer, if I've guessed right at what you were seeking. Either way, read the Swift Tour, and go forth young padawan in your coding career!

Answer (score 3):

This is a truly horrible example because they're not using `URL` correctly, they're using the deprecated `NSURLConnection`, and even if you did want to use `sendSynchronousRequest` (which you don't), that code sample's attempt to capture the response is simply incorrect.

The correct syntax is:

```
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY")!)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    }

    // now use `data` here
}
task.resume()

// but don't try to use `data` here
```

In answer to your question of how to understand the `URLRequest(url:)` syntax, you can refer to the [documentation for that initialization method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlrequest/2011457-init). Basically, that documentation is telling you that this initialization method of the `URLRequest` structure takes three parameters of which the first parameter is has a name of `url` (and the second and third parameters have default values, so you just don't have to include them). So, with a structure named `URLRequest` and an initialization method whose only required argument is the one named `url`, the syntax is:

```
let request = URLRequest(url: requestedURL)
```

Where the `requestedURL` is the instance of the `URL` for that request.

I wouldn't be surprised, though, if it was difficult to follow the documentation page until you're more familiar with the Swift language, so I'd suggest you first check out the [Resources](https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/) page, notably the [The Swift Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html). Notably, its [Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) chapter describes how you define a class with an `init` method, and how you instantiate objects with a particular `init` method. But really go through that entire guide (and/or find some Swift tutorials via Google) before wasting any time trying to decipher code.

---

As Vadian points out, because there is another rendition of `dataTask` that accepts a `URL` directly, we can simplify this further:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY")!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    }

    // now use `data` here
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: For a GET request an explicit `URLRequest` is actually not needed. `dataTask(with:` accepts also an `URL`

Comment: Absolutely. I was trying to help the Raymond understand the syntax of the `URLRequest` initialization in his question, providing a graceful transition from his horrible example to something that would work.